# Are there a pre- and post-install hooks before going into reboot in Ubuntu Desktop Installer (as of 24.04; 23.04+ changes)?

Tags: system-installation, iso, customization, 23.10, 24.04

I want to customize installation CD for Ubuntu Desktop. Version 24.04.

- Anybody, to confirm, that the functionality has been lost and there is no full replacement?
- Anybody, to tell, how a customization *intended* to be done? I found few hacks. I'm disappointed how someone should use the workflow: how is customization intended to be implemented by an end-user. Not a hacks, but how was it planned from authors perspective to do by someone else: selective screens with storage layout, language and so on, along with customization with scripting.

This post was hidden and automatically deleted CommunityBot without an answers from past summer ([URL to deleted q.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478772)). But IMHO it's a hot question of my year.

The question is about installer's functionality. The question is same for all distribution releases with modern Ubuntu Desktop Installer (UDI). Starting from 23.04 and up to 24.04+.

During Ubuntu install there is cascade of Ubuntu installers: UDI, Subiquity, Curtin.

I want to trigger a custom hooks before and after installer's job. Technically I want to do a thing, which during installation of Ubuntu by UDI installer is equivalent of early-commands and late-commands from Subiquity's autoinstall.

I succeeded with the server ISO customization: ubuntu-desktop package can be installed with Subiquity and with it's autoinstall. It do not fit.

Tell me please,

Are there any pre- and post-install customization hooks for UDI? Especially for doing of smth. before first boot of target system.

Is there a file or hook, where it is possible to put inside ISO image my own scripts for customization of a system to be installed with UDI? How it is called, what is it's path?

In general, how do I customize an installation media?

Thank you!

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *noble* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: With the 23.10 release; you had one *flavor* to look at for clues; with *noble* (or what will be 24.04 when it reaches RC and release) there are many more *flavors* using it where you can look for clues. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS however is only on-topic here when it exists; as its currently still in *alpha* being Ubuntu *noble* (*though yes the weeks are counting down to beta*)

Comment: My question about installer released 1 year ago along with 23.04, 23.10. 24.04 will be released as LTS in 25~30 days with the installer on board.

The installer, evidently, already may have a way for an end user to insert an customization. Installers are not changing fundamentally every half year.

My question is not about particular Ubuntu release. My question about UDI installer's way intended by authors for a customs insertion by end-users. UDI is used across several releases.

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't currently exist; 23.04 & 23.10 had `ubiquity` ISOs available as backup (and `ubuntu-desktop-installer` has been around since 19.10 though was just *canary* installer; ISOs available if you wanted to try it for years available at cdimage.ubuntu.com); less than an hour ago I got notified of an issue currently with `ubuntu-desktop-installer` cannot be fixed in time thus the 'fix' is to DISABLE that feature for 24.04 !  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS doesn't yet exist; features are not *firm* yet as we're still in ***alpha***

Comment: FYI:  The feature (*I didn't provide details for*) will work for Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop however; the plan currently is to just disable/prevent that type of re-install method for Ubuntu *noble* (or what will be 24.04 on release)... ie. release can matter.

Comment: My question is about the way the authors suggest to use with UDI (Ubuntu Desktop Installer) for OS customization during install. UDI was used as main installer in 23.04, 23.10 and upcoming daily builds of 24.04 use UDI too.

Ubiquity explicitly has been marked as already obsolete. I know well how to implement desired things with Ubiquity. I'm searching for knowledge concerning UDI.